# ANR in com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk, android-anr-dialog

I am having problems deploying an app onto the Google Play Store. The exception that is getting returned is such:

```
05-10 14:14:31.383: E/ActivityManager(1572): ANR in com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
05-10 14:14:31.383: E/ActivityManager(1572): PID: 16601
05-10 14:14:31.383: E/ActivityManager(1572): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.accounts.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED flg=0x5000010 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.apps.tiktok.account.data.device.DeviceAccountsChangedReceiver_Receiver }
```

https://pastebin.com/ApYNL7KC

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am having the exact same issue with Google Play Store

Comment: I have the same issue. My previous releases did not have this error. There is no related change.

Answer (score 2):

You see this as error in Google automated tests. Based on the description this is something that won't happen in real life to real users.

Google Play console had and still has problems in testing when it opens WebView and shows some crashes that don't exist (and can't exist unless WebView crashes itself).

Comment: This is good to know, but we were unable to publish our application because of this automated test.

Comment: @Bart this CAN'T block your publishing of the app.

Comment: To my knowledge, it can if you're using AppCenter.

Answer (score 0):

While I could not find the cause of this error yet, I could get rid of it for now.

There were two clues of where the error can be,

1. Error message/log has the phrase "**Broadcast of Intent**"
2. By looking at the recording provided at launch report error details. The crash happened when App was being launched by other **intent** (than the main)

[image: Video in Error details here]

To get rid of the error
I removed this deep link for now. (Settings>Deep Link 1).The next report does not have the crash.

[image: Remove Deep Link]

Comment: So you had a deep link previously and deleting it helped? Because i have the same error but without any deep links provided.

Comment: yes.. It worked after removing the deep link.. Though it could be purely random because I did not do many iterations. It's been about six months now.. I may not remember all details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with "tel" anchor link to call our company toll free number.  I just changed to plain text but obviously not great.  I'm not clear why that was an issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).